# How to open Edge in the current desktop on Win 10

Tags: windows-10

I'm using the new [multiple desktops](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-use-multiple-desktops-in-windows-10/#!) feature of Win 10. Everything is great except for programs that I need opened in multiple desktops - for example, my browser. For example, lets say I have two desktops, and one has Edge open already. When I go to the other desktop, if I try to open Edge, it snaps me back to the previous desktop. (Yes, I can create a new tab there, pop it own into its own window, and then drag it over to the 2nd desktop, but that is way too cumbersome). Have any of you found a way around this?

Comment: You can use Shift + WinKey + Arrow to quickly move a window to the next monitor in the direction of the arrow. WinKey + Arrows (no shift) will move the window around in the "snap" halves/quadrants.

Comment: That is pretty nifty, but I think you misunderstood the question. Windows 10 "multiple desktops" is different from "multiple monitors". Feel free to check out the link in my question.

Comment: You're right. I think the terminology is needlessly confusing, with desktops referring to both multiple screens and virtual desktops. Workspaces is a much more common term that MS should've adopted.

Answer (score 1):

It is a noted ask that Microsoft is currently looking into.  Until the ask is addressed, you can:

1. create a new page on your existing open Edge browser
2. Then drag it off the windows to create an open secondary Edge browser
3. Next drag the new Edge browser window to your secondary virtual desktop

That should work for now.

Comment: What you're describing is the same workaround that I described in my question as cumbersome.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no other way at the moment.  Microsoft is looking into the inquiry.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @AnthonyBartolo Do you have a link you can reference to confirm that MS is actually looking into this? If so, could you post it? This is a tough question to google effectively. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To open an Edge shortcut (including a URL) in the current virtual desktop, create a new Windows shortcut (right-click context menu), using this format:

**microsoft-edge:{URL}**

That will force Edge to always open the URL (instead of just switching to an existing instance window that already has a similar URL open) on the current desktop.

To pin it to the Start Menu:

1. Create that shortcut above in a subfolder under {userfolder}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs, such as "Shortcuts".
2. Open the Start Menu and scroll down to your new folder name ("Shortcuts"), right click on the new shortcut, click "Pin to Start".

That will bypass all of the new Edge 2021 updates that force Edge shortcuts to try to always use existing open browser windows.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the Edge taskbar icon and select Edge. This will launch Edge in the current window.